# Power Method in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, eigenvector

I would like to implement the [Power Method](http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews//n2003/PowerMethodMod.html) for determining the dominant eigenvalue and eigenvector of a matrix in MATLAB.

Here's what I wrote so far:

```
%function to implement power method to compute dominant
%eigenvalue/eigenevctor
function [m,y_final]=power_method(A,x);
m=0;
n=length(x);
y_final=zeros(n,1);
y_final=x;
tol=1e-3;
while(1)
    mold=m;
 y_final=A*y_final;
 m=max(y_final);
 y_final=y_final/m;
 if (m-mold)<tol
     break;
 end
end
end
```

With the above code, here is a numerical example:

```
 A=[1 1 -2;-1 2 1; 0 1 -1]

A =

     1     1    -2
    -1     2     1
     0     1    -1

>> x=[1 1 1];
>> x=x';
>> [m,y_final]=power_method(A,x);
>> A*x

ans =

     0
     2
     0
```

When comparing with the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the above matrix in MATLAB, I did:

```
[V,D]=eig(A)

V =

    0.3015   -0.8018    0.7071
    0.9045   -0.5345    0.0000
    0.3015   -0.2673    0.7071


D =

    2.0000         0         0
         0    1.0000         0
         0         0   -1.0000
```

The eigenvalue coincides, but the eigenvector should be approaching `[1/3 1 1/3]`.  Here, I get:

```
 y_final

y_final =

    0.5000
    1.0000
    0.5000
```

Is this acceptable to see this inaccuracy, or am I making some mistake?

Comment: [1/3 1 1/3] is dominant eigenvector  or after each iteration eigenvector is approaching [1/3 1 1//3]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the correct implementation, but you're not checking **both** the eigenvector and eigenvalue for convergence.  You're only checking the eigenvalue for convergence.  The power method estimates both the prominent eigenvector and eigenvalue, so it's probably a good idea to check to see if **both** converged.  When I did that, I managed to get `[1/3 1 1/3]`.  Here is how I modified your code to facilitate this:

```
function [m,y_final]=power_method(A,x)
m=0;
n=length(x);
y_final=x;
tol=1e-10; %// Change - make tolerance more small to ensure convergence
while(1)
     mold = m;
     y_old=y_final; %// Change - Save old eigenvector
     y_final=A*y_final;
     m=max(y_final);
     y_final=y_final/m;
     if abs(m-mold) < tol && norm(y_final-y_old,2) < tol %// Change - Check for both
         break;
     end
end
end
```

When I run the above code with your example input, I get:

```
>> [m,y_final]=power_method(A,x)

m =

     2


y_final =

    0.3333
    1.0000
    0.3333
```

---

On a side note with regards to `eig`, MATLAB most likely scaled that eigenvector using another norm.  Remember that eigenvectors **are not unique**  and are accurate up to scale.  If you want to be sure, simply take the first column of `V`, which coincides with the dominant eigenvector, and divide by the largest value so that we can get one component to be normalized with the value of 1, just like the Power Method:

```
>> [V,D] = eig(A);
>> V(:,1) / max(abs(V(:,1)))

ans =

    0.3333
    1.0000
    0.3333
```

This agrees with what you have observed.

Comment: Perhaps we should use `max(abs(...))` to renormalize the working vector?

Comment: @TavinCole Good point! I I'll make an edit.  If you found this post useful I'd love an upvote!