# Finding the Largest Eigenvalue Using the Power method

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, eigenvector, eigenvalue

For this problem, I have to take a large 100 by 100 matrix of randomly generated values and an initial x vector and try to obtain the largest absolute value of the eigenvalues and the associated convectors as well as the number of iterations.

The power method as described:

[image]

I have to find the absolute val of the largest eigenvalue, the corresponding eigenvector, and the number of iterations.

My code:

```
%% problem 2b: Power method
% code snippet from class generates A and x
nx = 10;
ex = ones(nx,1);
Dxx = spdiags([ex -2*ex ex], [-1 0 1], nx, nx);
A = kron(Dxx, speye(nx)) + kron(speye(nx), Dxx);
rng(2);
x = rand(nx*nx,1); % initial vector

yk = [] % stores yk values
count = 0; % keeps track of iterations
value = 1; % 1 to ensure while loop is entered
tolerance = 10^(-6); % tol

while (value >= tolerance)
    yk = A*x; % yk = A*xk
    xnext = yk/norm(yk); % Xk+1=yk/2norm(yk)
    rk = dot(xnext,(A*xnext)); % rk = Xk+1 * (A*Xk+1)
    count = count+1; % iterate count
    value = norm(yk - rk*x); % update tolerance check
    x = xnext;
end
value

x % final eigenvector
rk % the largest eignvalue in abs value
count % the number of iterations
```

According to the answers, my largest eigenvalue—rk—is correct, but the corresponding eigenvector and the number of iterations is incorrect. Can someone clarify this for me? The eigenvalue and the eigenvector agrees when I use:

```
[C, D] = eigs(A)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure?  It looks correct to me.

When I produce `C` and `D` with `eigs`, I get:

```
>> [C, D] = eigs(A)

C =

    0.0520    0.0170    0.0531    0.0158   -0.0358   -0.0144
   -0.0788   -0.0433   -0.0894   -0.0327    0.0626    0.0277
    0.0717    0.0801    0.0973    0.0510   -0.0741   -0.0387
   -0.0437   -0.1180   -0.0743   -0.0694    0.0684    0.0466
    0.0200    0.1424    0.0277    0.0855   -0.0486   -0.0507
   -0.0200   -0.1424    0.0277   -0.0959    0.0217    0.0507
    0.0437    0.1180   -0.0743    0.0974    0.0038   -0.0466
   -0.0717   -0.0801    0.0973   -0.0876   -0.0204    0.0387
    0.0788    0.0433   -0.0894    0.0664    0.0243   -0.0277
   -0.0520   -0.0170    0.0531   -0.0358   -0.0158    0.0144
   -0.0892   -0.0116   -0.0894   -0.0243    0.0664    0.0277
    0.1308    0.0427    0.1504    0.0511   -0.1157   -0.0531
   -0.1090   -0.0972   -0.1637   -0.0814    0.1359    0.0743
    0.0494    0.1585    0.1250    0.1135   -0.1236   -0.0894
   -0.0009   -0.1993   -0.0466   -0.1427    0.0849    0.0973
    0.0009    0.1993   -0.0466    0.1627   -0.0333   -0.0973
   -0.0494   -0.1585    0.1250   -0.1671   -0.0149    0.0894
    0.1090    0.0972   -0.1637    0.1517    0.0456   -0.0743
   -0.1308   -0.0427    0.1504   -0.1157   -0.0511    0.0531
    0.0892    0.0116   -0.0894    0.0626    0.0327   -0.0277
    0.1051   -0.0223    0.0973    0.0204   -0.0876   -0.0387
   -0.1453    0.0142   -0.1637   -0.0456    0.1517    0.0743
    0.0999    0.0326    0.1781    0.0777   -0.1760   -0.1038
   -0.0060   -0.0973   -0.1360   -0.1151    0.1560    0.1250
   -0.0674    0.1433    0.0507    0.1521   -0.1004   -0.1360
    0.0674   -0.1433    0.0507   -0.1801    0.0282    0.1360
    0.0060    0.0973   -0.1360    0.1902    0.0377   -0.1250
   -0.0999   -0.0326    0.1781   -0.1760   -0.0777    0.1038
    0.1453   -0.0142   -0.1637    0.1359    0.0814   -0.0743
   -0.1051    0.0223    0.0973   -0.0741   -0.0510    0.0387
   -0.1049    0.0695   -0.0743   -0.0038    0.0974    0.0466
    0.1334   -0.0988    0.1250    0.0149   -0.1671   -0.0894
   -0.0622    0.0750   -0.1360   -0.0377    0.1902    0.1250
   -0.0626   -0.0205    0.1038    0.0714   -0.1617   -0.1504
    0.1571   -0.0229   -0.0387   -0.1100    0.0926    0.1637
   -0.1571    0.0229   -0.0387    0.1437   -0.0057   -0.1637
    0.0626    0.0205    0.1038   -0.1617   -0.0714    0.1504
    0.0622   -0.0750   -0.1360    0.1560    0.1151   -0.1250
   -0.1334    0.0988    0.1250   -0.1236   -0.1135    0.0894
    0.1049   -0.0695   -0.0743    0.0684    0.0694   -0.0466
    0.1002   -0.1031    0.0277   -0.0217   -0.0959   -0.0507
   -0.1184    0.1604   -0.0466    0.0333    0.1627    0.0973
    0.0302   -0.1555    0.0507   -0.0282   -0.1801   -0.1360
    0.1133    0.1112   -0.0387    0.0057    0.1437    0.1637
   -0.2201   -0.0719    0.0144    0.0290   -0.0656   -0.1781
    0.2201    0.0719    0.0144   -0.0656   -0.0290    0.1781
   -0.1133   -0.1112   -0.0387    0.0926    0.1100   -0.1637
   -0.0302    0.1555    0.0507   -0.1004   -0.1521    0.1360
    0.1184   -0.1604   -0.0466    0.0849    0.1427   -0.0973
   -0.1002    0.1031    0.0277   -0.0486   -0.0855    0.0507
   -0.1002    0.1031    0.0277    0.0486    0.0855    0.0507
    0.1184   -0.1604   -0.0466   -0.0849   -0.1427   -0.0973
   -0.0302    0.1555    0.0507    0.1004    0.1521    0.1360
   -0.1133   -0.1112   -0.0387   -0.0926   -0.1100   -0.1637
    0.2201    0.0719    0.0144    0.0656    0.0290    0.1781
   -0.2201   -0.0719    0.0144   -0.0290    0.0656   -0.1781
    0.1133    0.1112   -0.0387   -0.0057   -0.1437    0.1637
    0.0302   -0.1555    0.0507    0.0282    0.1801   -0.1360
   -0.1184    0.1604   -0.0466   -0.0333   -0.1627    0.0973
    0.1002   -0.1031    0.0277    0.0217    0.0959   -0.0507
    0.1049   -0.0695   -0.0743   -0.0684   -0.0694   -0.0466
   -0.1334    0.0988    0.1250    0.1236    0.1135    0.0894
    0.0622   -0.0750   -0.1360   -0.1560   -0.1151   -0.1250
    0.0626    0.0205    0.1038    0.1617    0.0714    0.1504
   -0.1571    0.0229   -0.0387   -0.1437    0.0057   -0.1637
    0.1571   -0.0229   -0.0387    0.1100   -0.0926    0.1637
   -0.0626   -0.0205    0.1038   -0.0714    0.1617   -0.1504
   -0.0622    0.0750   -0.1360    0.0377   -0.1902    0.1250
    0.1334   -0.0988    0.1250   -0.0149    0.1671   -0.0894
   -0.1049    0.0695   -0.0743    0.0038   -0.0974    0.0466
   -0.1051    0.0223    0.0973    0.0741    0.0510    0.0387
    0.1453   -0.0142   -0.1637   -0.1359   -0.0814   -0.0743
   -0.0999   -0.0326    0.1781    0.1760    0.0777    0.1038
    0.0060    0.0973   -0.1360   -0.1902   -0.0377   -0.1250
    0.0674   -0.1433    0.0507    0.1801   -0.0282    0.1360
   -0.0674    0.1433    0.0507   -0.1521    0.1004   -0.1360
   -0.0060   -0.0973   -0.1360    0.1151   -0.1560    0.1250
    0.0999    0.0326    0.1781   -0.0777    0.1760   -0.1038
   -0.1453    0.0142   -0.1637    0.0456   -0.1517    0.0743
    0.1051   -0.0223    0.0973   -0.0204    0.0876   -0.0387
    0.0892    0.0116   -0.0894   -0.0626   -0.0327   -0.0277
   -0.1308   -0.0427    0.1504    0.1157    0.0511    0.0531
    0.1090    0.0972   -0.1637   -0.1517   -0.0456   -0.0743
   -0.0494   -0.1585    0.1250    0.1671    0.0149    0.0894
    0.0009    0.1993   -0.0466   -0.1627    0.0333   -0.0973
   -0.0009   -0.1993   -0.0466    0.1427   -0.0849    0.0973
    0.0494    0.1585    0.1250   -0.1135    0.1236   -0.0894
   -0.1090   -0.0972   -0.1637    0.0814   -0.1359    0.0743
    0.1308    0.0427    0.1504   -0.0511    0.1157   -0.0531
   -0.0892   -0.0116   -0.0894    0.0243   -0.0664    0.0277
   -0.0520   -0.0170    0.0531    0.0358    0.0158    0.0144
    0.0788    0.0433   -0.0894   -0.0664   -0.0243   -0.0277
   -0.0717   -0.0801    0.0973    0.0876    0.0204    0.0387
    0.0437    0.1180   -0.0743   -0.0974   -0.0038   -0.0466
   -0.0200   -0.1424    0.0277    0.0959   -0.0217    0.0507
    0.0200    0.1424    0.0277   -0.0855    0.0486   -0.0507
   -0.0437   -0.1180   -0.0743    0.0694   -0.0684    0.0466
    0.0717    0.0801    0.0973   -0.0510    0.0741   -0.0387
   -0.0788   -0.0433   -0.0894    0.0327   -0.0626    0.0277
    0.0520    0.0170    0.0531   -0.0158    0.0358   -0.0144


D =

   -7.2287         0         0         0         0         0
         0   -7.2287         0         0         0         0
         0         0   -7.3650         0         0         0
         0         0         0   -7.6015         0         0
         0         0         0         0   -7.6015         0
         0         0         0         0         0   -7.8380
```

Also, `rk` from your Power Method gives:

```
>> rk

rk =

   -7.8380
```

`rk` is the last eigenvalue produced by `eigs`, and that corresponds to the last eigenvector / last column in `C`.  If we compare `x` and the last column of `C`, we get:

```
>> format long g;
>> [x C(:,6)]

ans =

       -0.0144315780109194       -0.0144314970153476
        0.0276939697943544         0.027693839969929
       -0.0387127177669401       -0.0387125927117545
        0.0465951447011548        0.0465950814247274
       -0.0507026743311123        -0.050702713752288
        0.0507025614842252        0.0507027137522879
       -0.0465948419885827       -0.0465950814247267
        0.0387123212977858        0.0387125927117535
        -0.027693605444773        -0.027693839969928
        0.0144313614593288         0.014431497015347
        0.0276940018504475        0.0276938399699289
       -0.0531443512380279        -0.053144089727102
        0.0742891786790794        0.0742889213946561
       -0.0894154487195339       -0.0894153064640425
        0.0972977421934561        0.0972977951770151
       -0.0972975256418808        -0.097297795177015
        0.0894148678184032        0.0894153064640416
       -0.0742884178603978        -0.074288921394655
        0.0531436520563511        0.0531440897271008
       -0.0276935862910177       -0.0276938399699281
       -0.0387128332167354       -0.0387125927117545
         0.074289314234918         0.074288921394656
        -0.103847201265651         -0.10384680347939
         0.124991879901604         0.124991635146944
         -0.13601036376947        -0.136010387888769
         0.136010061056953         0.136010387888769
        -0.124991067873139        -0.124991635146943
         0.103846137734539         0.103846803479389
       -0.0742883368647708       -0.0742889213946555
        0.0387122523156699         0.038712592711754
        0.0465953928808543        0.0465950814247275
       -0.0894158214731441       -0.0894153064640426
         0.124992172891791         0.124991635146944
        -0.150442250463584        -0.150441884904116
         0.163704276053648         0.163704227858698
        -0.163703911704186        -0.163704227858698
         0.150441273093578         0.150441884904117
        -0.124990892809312        -0.124991635146944
        0.0894146450953342        0.0894153064640427
       -0.0465946936993567       -0.0465950814247274
       -0.0507030799451604       -0.0507027137522887
        0.0972984079372535        0.0972977951770161
        -0.136011046217971         -0.13601038788877
         0.163704713723789         0.163704227858698
         -0.17813587316184        -0.178135724874045
         0.178135476692881         0.178135724874045
        -0.163703650193004        -0.163704227858699
         0.136009653288871          0.13601038788877
       -0.0972971278549844       -0.0972977951770159
        0.0507023191267988        0.0507027137522887
        0.0507031083768884        0.0507027137522886
       -0.0972984624973554        -0.097297795177016
         0.136011122486338          0.13601038788877
         -0.16370480552164        -0.163704227858699
          0.17813597305228         0.178135724874046
        -0.178135576583388        -0.178135724874046
         0.163703741991037         0.163704227858699
        -0.136009729557476         -0.13601038788877
        0.0972971824153056        0.0972977951770162
       -0.0507023475586572       -0.0507027137522885
       -0.0465954691491656       -0.0465950814247277
         0.089415967831003        0.0894153064640427
        -0.124992377482224        -0.124991635146945
         0.150442496711966         0.150441884904117
        -0.163704544010458        -0.163704227858698
         0.163704179661178         0.163704227858698
        -0.150441519342448        -0.150441884904117
         0.124991097400385         0.124991635146944
       -0.0894147914537812       -0.0894153064640427
        0.0465947699680175        0.0465950814247277
          0.03871293310698        0.0387125927117539
       -0.0742895059229478       -0.0742889213946556
         0.103847469222133          0.10384680347939
        -0.124992202418397        -0.124991635146944
         0.136010714718256          0.13601038788877
        -0.136010412005978        -0.136010387888769
         0.124991390390572         0.124991635146944
        -0.103846405691859        -0.103846803479389
        0.0742885285535708        0.0742889213946558
       -0.0387123522063723       -0.0387125927117542
       -0.0276940936481785       -0.0276938399699281
        0.0531445273966335        0.0531440897271008
       -0.0742894249273207       -0.0742889213946552
         0.089415745107934        0.0894153064640417
        -0.097298064710459       -0.0972977951770146
         0.097297848159103        0.0972977951770148
       -0.0894151642073914       -0.0894153064640414
        0.0742886641094094        0.0742889213946553
       -0.0531438282156646        -0.053144089727101
        0.0276936780891695        0.0276938399699285
        0.0144316325710059        0.0144314970153468
       -0.0276940744944232       -0.0276938399699279
        0.0387128641248642        0.0387125927117535
       -0.0465953208599396       -0.0465950814247267
        0.0507028660194621        0.0507027137522877
       -0.0507027531727052       -0.0507027137522875
         0.046595018147717        0.0465950814247267
       -0.0387124676561676       -0.0387125927117538
        0.0276937101452626        0.0276938399699282
       -0.0144314160196653       -0.0144314970153473
```

Also looks fine.  Shall we do another test?  Let's find the maximum deviation between `x` and the last eigenvector of `C`:

```
>> max(abs(x - C(:,6)))

ans =

      7.42337632364531e-07
```

That also agrees with your tolerance you specified at the beginning, where it's `< 1e-6`.

---

As such, I don't see anything wrong with your code.  You should probably double-check your theory on the Power Method because it produces what you expect.

Comment: Thanks, that's reassuring. I'll ask my professor about this; I just don't understand how I can get the eigenvalue correct but the eigenvector and the iteration count wrong.

Comment: @JackL. - I think I know where you may be getting confused.  I'll update my answer... but in the power method, some people normalize the eigenvector so that the maximum component is set to 1.  What you are doing is normalizing by the 2-norm, which is the proper way to do it.  This is probably where the number of iterations and eigenvector are different... but remember, eigenvectors are non-unique.  They're equivalent up to a scale factor.  Let me update my post.

Comment: @JackL. - Yeah never mind.  I already answered something similar in the past lol.  Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29198277/power-method-in-matlab/29199316#29199316 - See if this method produces the "right" iterations and eigenvector, but remember that eigenvectors are valid up to a scale.  Let me know what your prof says.